# Display special characters and symbols from .docx in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, docx

I am writing an app that needs to read in .docx files.  Some of these files contain mathematical equations and formulas that involve fractions, special symbols, etc., and when I try to read them in to display in a UITextView, they do not show up.  Is there any work-around, for this?  Perhaps a UITextView isn't the best way to display this data?

I am very new to xcode, so I may be missing something very simple.  Thanks :)

Comment: Try a `UIWebView` or `QLPreviewController`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @rmaddy I've looked at Web Views but I've never heard of a QLPreviewController, gonna take a look now!